# opendaylight: how easy is it to tweak it

Tags: controller, opendaylight, sdn

I am looking for a controller but i need to modify the following behaviours:

1. algorithm to create entries in the routing table
2. forwarding routing table of primary and alternate paths to each registered node (agent on each node must be changed in order to keep both the primary and alternate paths i guess)
3. Possibility from the controller to TX proprietary messages that will need to be sent periodically from the controller to each of its registered nodes (agent on each node must be changed in order to process these messages too i guess)
4. Possibility from the controller to RX proprietary messages that will need to be sent periodically from the controller to each of its registered nodes (agent on each node must be changed in order to send these messages too i guess)

Are these operations easy to hook up to and modify based on what i intend to do above when using opendaylight? Would that be easier using another controller like floodlight.. or others?

thanks for your feedback

simon

Answer (score 0):

OpenDayLight is a considerably large project. Many other products/libraries are built around OpenDayLight controller. Its Apache Karaf based OSGi model makes it easier to create more feature bundles for OpenDaylight. You may like to have a look at the other products such as groupbasedpolicy and affinity hosted under OpenDaylight, along with the controller. These projects provide more features, probably helping you achieve your goal easier.

I have built OpenDaylight and the related projects from the source code - 
http://kkpradeeban.blogspot.com/2014/10/building-open-daylight-packages-on.html It was actually pretty straight forward.

Floodlight is a well used controller as well. An academic research project named Beacon was forked to create Floodlight, which carries on with an Apache license. Hence, Floodlight is also well-received by the academics. OpenDaylight holds an Eclipse license, and is backed by Linux foundation and industrial giants such as Cisco and IBM.

Your choice also depends on your requirements, whether you are considering for a production, or for researching/academics.